# Why doesn't cut work as expected in R?

Tags: r

Why don't these two return the same result?

```
    D = data.frame( x=c( 0.6 ) )

    D$binned = cut( D$x, seq( 0.50,0.70,0.025 ), include.lowest=TRUE, right=FALSE )
    D # 0.6 is binned correctly as [0.6,0.625)

    D$binned = cut( D$x, seq( 0.55,0.65,0.025 ), include.lowest=TRUE, right=FALSE )
    D # 0.6 is binned incorrectly as [0.575,0.6)
```

Comment: Variant on http://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/892313

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`D$binned = cut( D$x, round(seq( 0.55,0.65,0.025 ),3), include.lowest=TRUE, right=FALSE )`

`D`

`x      binned`

`1 0.6 [0.6,0.625)`

Answer (score 5):

Representation error. Floating point approximation of numbers is only exact if the number is a combination of certain powers of 2. Other numbers are mapped to these numbers. Different algorithms to produce a number may do so in different ways and have different errors associated with them (ie above or below the expected value). In this case:

```
print(D$x,digits=22)
[1] 0.5999999999999999777955
print(seq(0.5,0.7,0.025)[5],digits=22)
[1] 0.5999999999999999777955
> print(seq(0.55,0.65,0.025)[3],digits=22)
[1] 0.6000000000000000888178
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. The errors are consistent, but ultimately the value depends on how it is calculated. The usual way of dealing with this is to only consider equality within a certain tolerance, however `cut` needs sharp break points.

Comment: However, if your numbers will always only have a few decimal points, you could bump the break points accordingly (eg, `seq( 0.55,0.65,0.025 ) - 0.000001` and see if that helps.

Comment: You might want to look at the source code for `hist.default` to see one approach